# Как убрать строки с ._ в начале при выводе?

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
import os
    def files(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            yield file

for file in files("."):  
    print(file)
```

при выводе я получаю:

```
file.py
file.txt
main.py
sorter.py
._sorter.py
renamed.csv
._file.txt
._renamed.csv
```

как мне убрать строки с ._ в начале?

Comment: `replace`......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при выводе, то так:

```
if not file.startswith('._'):
    print(file)
```

Или можно их вообще не генерировать:

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)) and not file.startswith('._'):
    yield file
```